# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service with intent has extras android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

This is my first post here, and I hope I do it well...

I'm trying to edit an Open Source Updater (YAOS Updater), and when I try to connect, it gives me an error.

I'll try to explain the better I can.

I've added a value in the JSON used to list all the files. the new value of each file is urlArchivo, which contains the complete url of the file.

This is the part of the code:

```
package org.yaosupdater.services;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.yaosupdater.R;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Query;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

@TargetApi(16)
public class DownloadService extends Service{

private DownloadManager dm;
private String nombre;
private String archivo;
private String urlArchivo;
private String[] mirrors;
private long enqueue;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid){
    super.onStart(intent, startid);
    dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    nombre = (String) bundle.get("nombre");
    Log.d("Dexafree", "Nombre: " +nombre);
    archivo = (String) bundle.get("archivo");
    Log.d("Dexafree", "Archivo: " +archivo);
    urlArchivo = (String) bundle.getString("urlArchivo");
    Log.d("Dexafree", "urlArchivo: " +urlArchivo);
    mirrors = (String[]) bundle.get("mirrors");
    URL url;
    int j = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while((j < mirrors.length)&&(!found)){
        try {
            url = new URL(urlArchivo);
            Log.d("Dexafree", "Intentando conectar a: " +urlArchivo);
            //url = new URL(urlArchivo);
            //Log.d("Dexafree", "Intentando conectar a: " +urlArchivo);
            URLConnection urlCon = url.openConnection();
            Log.d("Dexafree", "Conexion abierta a: " +urlCon);
            Log.d("Dexafree", "Debe ser igual a: " + urlArchivo);
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream());
            found = true;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("MIUIEsUpdater", "El archivo " +urlArchivo +" no se encontró.");
            found = false;
        }
        j++;
    }   
    j--;
```

The variable urlArchivo, in the logcat, gets the right URL, I mean, the

```
    Log.d("Dexafree", "Intentando conectar a: " +urlArchivo);
```

Returns the correct complete url of the file, but it FC, showing the next logcat

```
08-19 14:51:40.417: E/Trace(4134): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-19 14:51:40.449: D/Dexafree(4134): Nombre: MODEM KF1
08-19 14:51:40.453: D/Dexafree(4134): Archivo: Modem_KF1.zip
08-19 14:51:40.453: D/Dexafree(4134): urlArchivo: http://content.wuala.com/contents/elitemovil/Galaxy_S/GT-I9000/carpetaprueba/Modem_KF1.zip
08-19 14:51:40.453: D/Dexafree(4134): Intentando conectar a: http://content.wuala.com/contents/elitemovil/Galaxy_S/GT-I9000/carpetaprueba/Modem_KF1.zip
08-19 14:51:40.453: D/Dexafree(4134): Conexion abierta a: libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://content.wuala.com/contents/elitemovil/Galaxy_S/GT-I9000/carpetaprueba/Modem_KF1.zip
08-19 14:51:40.453: D/Dexafree(4134): Debe ser igual a: http://content.wuala.com/contents/elitemovil/Galaxy_S/GT-I9000/carpetaprueba/Modem_KF1.zip
08-19 14:51:40.457: D/AndroidRuntime(4134): Shutting down VM
08-19 14:51:40.457: W/dalvikvm(4134): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40edb300)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service org.yaosupdater.services.DownloadService@416c0c38 with Intent { cmp=org.yaosupdater/.services.DownloadService (has extras) }: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2507)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at org.yaosupdater.services.DownloadService.onStart(DownloadService.java:73)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2490)
08-19 14:51:40.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4134):     ... 10 more
```

I hope I've posted all the information needed to solve this problem. If any more information is needed, please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

Android throws `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` because...

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged.

Create a separate thread for your networking operations, it's telling you that basically.

> Potentially long running operations such as network or database
>   operations, or computationally expensive calculations such as resizing
>   bitmaps should be done in a child thread
>
> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is
>   going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such
>   as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to
>   do that work.

[Source1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) [Source2](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html) [Source3](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

You could have investigated this by yourself, but eh - do it next time.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer!
But this is a separate file, this isn't the main .java file...
I think you are saying that :S

Comment: @sherpya Nope, check the Source3 ref link I gave.

Comment: ah yes, but IntentService does